# vim how to combine lines containing same id

Tags: vim, neovim

I have a csv file and I want to combine lines with same id. Example:

```
ID,Name
1113,Firefox
1114,Chrome
1113,InternetExplorer
```

and it should look like:

```
ID,Name
1113,"Firefox,InternetExplorer"
1114,Chrome
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Awk might be a solution for you, something like this might be sufficient:

```
:2,$!awk -F, '{ a[$1] = (a[$1] ? a[$1] "," : "") $2 } END { for (p in a) print p "," a[p] }'
```

It would join lines on their first column and concatenate all the second columns with a comma:

```
ID,Name
1113,Firefox,InternetExplorer
1114,Chrome
```

The second column isn't quoted when outputted, nor is the sorting guaranteed.

Comment: It is what i searched for, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For VIM approach,

1. Sort from the second line to end of file.

```
:2,$sort
```

2. Create Marco 'a' starting from second line beginning

```
qa              ---> Record Macro 'a' 
vw"1y           ---> Copy column 1 value including "," to register '1'
V               ---> Select whole line
G?<CR>1<Enter>  ---> Go to end of file then search backward for last occurrence of 
                     register '1' to select all lines with same column 1 value
:'<,'>join      ---> Join selected lines 
:.s/ <CR>1/,/ge ---> Replace register '1' with a space in front to "," 
0wa             ---> Go to begin of line and move to the "," then append
"               ---> Append "
<ESC>$a         ---> Back to command mode and go to end of line then append 
"               ---> Append "
<ESC>j0         ---> Back to command mode and move 1 line down and go to start of line
1               ---> Complete Marco
```

Then play Macro 'a' any number of time like

```
1000@a          ---> execute 1000 times
```

---

Constraint:
**Will not work when column 2 contains value of  `{column 1},`**